# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Android

Tags: android, flutter

`Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\src\projects\flutter_ornek\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\batuf.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\ea4ydi90mwjg9g63m7r6nimmx).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like gradle is broken, for me I deleted gradle\caches and opened the android directory of the project in android, and it reinstalled gradle by itself.